# bcdedit cannot be found by rust executable

Tags: windows, bcdedit

I am trying to call bcdedit from within a rust executable using std::process::Command.

When executing the resulting program on Windows 10 in an administrator command prompt I get:

`'bcdedit' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`.

- Calling bcdedit directly in the same shell works just fine.
- Calling it with its absolute path makes no difference.
- Calling other executables works ok.
- Calling bcdedit directly without using cmd.exe returns `error: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "The system cannot find the file specified." }`.

This happens on Windows 10 Pro, version 1903, Build 18362.657. I have another Windows 10 installed (Windows 10 Pro, version 1809, build 17763.1039) on which this works ok.

I have a rust snippet that exposes the problem:

```rust
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use std::env::args;
fn main() {
    let mut cmd_args = args();
    let cmd = if let Some(arg1) = cmd_args.nth(1) {
        arg1
    } else {
        String::from("dir")
    };

    println!("command is '{}'", cmd);
    match Command::new("cmd.exe")
        .arg("/c")
        .arg(&cmd)
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(Stdio::piped())
        .output() {
        Ok(output) => {
            println!("Executed '{}', success: {}", cmd, output.status.success());
            println!("stdout: '{}'", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout));
            println!("stderr: '{}'", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stderr));
        }
        Err(why) => {
            eprintln!("Failed to execute '{}', error: {:?}", &cmd, why);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Msgbox box out the command you are executing.

Comment: Maybe run Process Monitor, see what's going on? Is it a 32 or 64-bit exe? Does it work %windir%\sysnative\bcdedit.exe for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HelpingHand's comment pointed in the right direction. 
Problem was that I accidentally created a 32bit executable while assuming I was creating 64 bit.
Apparently bcdedit on 64bit windows is only available as 64bit and as such is not accessible for 32bit executables in the normal location (`C:\Windows\system32\bcdedit.exe`). It can be accessed though at `C:\Windows\sysnative\bcdedit.exe`.

Comment: Questions asked in an answer cannot be answered by the community.  If you want an answer to your question, it has to be submitted as a question, so an answer can be submitted